# How to install smarty3 into specified directory such as `/usr/share/php5` with `apt-get install`?

Tags: apt

```
apt-get install smarty3
dpkg -L smarty3
/usr/share/php/smarty3
```

The smarty3 was installed on `/usr/share/doc/smarty3 and /usr/share/php/smarty3`.
How to install smarty3 into specified directory such as `/usr/share/php5` with `apt-get install`?

Comment: Why do you want that? `/usr/share/php` is where packages are supposed to install PHP modules.

Comment: Short answer is you don't, not with apt or apt-get, which get their install instructions from the package it downloaded to install.

Comment: My  PHP is php5  ,/usr/share/php5